# Spring Security Angular 2

Tags: java, spring, angular, spring-security, cors

I was wondering if someone can help me about a problem between Angular2 and Spring Security. Let me explain my issue the best I can.

I do a form (for the example, a very simple form) in Angular2, and with my Login service, I send it in my security page. In my localhost:4200 (angular) I send the username and password that I have juste enter to the localhost:8080/login (spring security) by POST.

The issue is, when I do this, i got this :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/login. Redirect from
>   'http://localhost:8080/login' to 'http://localhost:8080/' has been
>   blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

however, it's because the localhost:8080/login make a redirection, and after this one, the CORS policy comes back even if I allow it everywhere in my Spring code.

The most ankward in it, if I enter the bad credential (like username:"user" but password: "pasodqki") I got this :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/login. Redirect from
>   'http://localhost:8080/login' to 'http://localhost:8080/login?error'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

And when I did it right, I got the first error and we can see one redirect to localhost:8080 and the other to localhost:8080/login?error, I don't know if it means something.

All my code is here : [MyProjectGithub](https://github.com/Raiteishi/SpringSecurity_Angular2). If anyone have an idea, please help me because I don't understand how we can make this link between Angular and Spring security and I don't find a lot of help on the internet, or I don't understand maybe...

My config :

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().cors();
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("USER")
        .and()
        .formLogin();
  }


@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```

Like this it works!

Comment: Thank @dur for having been so patient and my problem is solve, I don't have any cors policy now.